# Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function order_completed(). on woocommerce_order_status_completed hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am getting the below error:

> [30-Nov-2021 16:08:47 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function order_completed(), 1 passed in /home/brantsho/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 305 and exactly 4 expected in /home/brantsho/public_html/wp-content/themes/glowing/functions.php:28
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/brantsho/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(305): order_completed()
> #1 /home/brantsho/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
> #2 /home/brantsho/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action()
> #3 /home/brantsho/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php(364): do_action()
> #4 /home/brantsho/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php(222): WC_Order->status_transition()
> #5 /home/brantsho/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php(334): WC_Order->save()
> #6 /home/brantsho/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php(530): WC_Order->update_status()
> #7 /home/brantsho/public_html/wp-incl in /home/brantsho/public_html/wp-content/themes/glowing/functions.php on line 28

But my functions.php seems fine:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

define('GLOWING_VERSION', '1.0.0');
define('GLOWING_FILE_HANDLER', basename(get_template_directory()) . '-');

/**
 * Inlcude theme functions
 */
include_once get_parent_theme_file_path('inc/require-plugin.php');
include_once get_parent_theme_file_path('inc/breadcrumbs.php');
include_once get_parent_theme_file_path('inc/core-functions.php');
include_once get_parent_theme_file_path('inc/template-functions.php');
include_once get_parent_theme_file_path('inc/template-tags.php');
include_once get_parent_theme_file_path('inc/customizer.php');
include_once get_parent_theme_file_path('inc/setup-data.php');
include_once get_parent_theme_file_path('inc/core.php');
include_once get_parent_theme_file_path('inc/elementor.php');
include_once get_parent_theme_file_path('inc/custom-css.php');
if (function_exists('WC')) {
    include_once get_parent_theme_file_path('inc/woocommerce.php');
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'order_completed',10,1);
function order_completed($order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order) {
  
  if( $new_status == "completed" ) {
    
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $total = $order->get_total();
    $coin_avl = $total*25/100;
    
    wp_update_user( array(
        'ID' => get_current_user_id(),
        'avl_coin' => $coin_avl
   ) ); 
    
  }
}
```

May you please help me to sort it out..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've passed `4` arguments to your callback function, but in your hook you specified only `1`.

Replace

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'order_completed',10,1);
```

With

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'order_completed', 10, 4);
```

Comment: life saver... silly mistake